# Number of possible ways to raise flags on poles

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ flagpoles and $r$ flags. Suppose we want to raise all flags, where a pole is allowed to have more than 1 flag:

1. How many possibilities are there if all flags are distinguishable
   (order matters), **order on the pole matters**?
2. How many possibilities are there if all flags are red?
3. How many different possibilities if the flags were colored red $p$ and white $q$ with ($p+q=r$)

For $1$) I thought since we can hang  more than $1$ flag and the flags are distinguishable for every flag we have $n$ possible poles so
$$\#\text{possibilites}=n\cdot n\cdot n\dots =n^r$$
**answer is wrong since order on the pole matters**

For $2)$ This one is a bit easier we had a lemma about it 
$$\#\text{possibilites}=\binom{n+r-1}{r}$$

$3$) Here I'm not sure, let $x$ be the number of the chosen flags, and $y$ the number of those that are red
$$\# \text{possibilites}=\binom{n}{x}=\sum_{y=0}^x\binom{n-p}{x-y}\binom{p}{y}$$

Is this correct or am I choosing the wrong model?

Comment: For part 1, if the order of the flags once on a pole matters then it seems to me like you have $r$ flags and $n-1$ dividers that separates the flags into $n$ groups (assuming a pole can have zero flags). Therefore you count the number of ways you can arrange $r+n-1$ objects when $n-1$ of them are indistinguishable. This also assumes each pole is distinguishable. Like in a unique location.

Comment: for 1 its distinguishable my bad. Isn't distinguishable and order matter the same thing (possible language barrier)?

Comment: They will often have similar meanings, but they do have a different nuance here.  The flags being distinguishable means that you can tell them apart and *depending on what sort of symmetry you allow* implies that if you swap the location of two or more distinguishable objects will result in a "different" arrangement.  Order matters here is in reference to order on a specific pole as well as order of the poles itself.  With two poles and three flags labeled $a,b,c$, one has the arrangement $\frac{a}{b}\mid c$ is different than $\frac{b}{a}\mid c$ despite the same flags being on the same poles.

Comment: An answer of $n^r$ assumes that order on the pole itself does not matter, only the set of colors appearing on each pole matters.  The question is slightly ambiguous, but I think it is safe to assume that each flag can only be hung on the pole in one way.  In practice in the real world, raising flags with special designs can be used for ships to signal eachother, sending short messages.  The order in which the flags appear on the pole is quite relevant and can change the meaning of the message.  For example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England_expects_that_every_man_will_do_his_duty).

Comment: Im so sorry yes order matters. I just reread the problem. I understand the difference but I cant seem to figure out a solution yet. Thanks for elaborating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to 1 is correct if you don't care about the order of the flags on each pole.  If you do, you should multiply by the factorials of the numbers of flags on each pole.  I don't see an easy answer for that.  For example, if $r=3,n=2$ you would get $2^3=8$ ways to distribute the flags to flagpoles.  Six of those have two flags on one pole and one on the other while two have all three flags on the same pole.  If order matters there are $2!\cdot 6+3!\cdot 2=24$ possibilities.

Your answer to 2 is fine

For 3 I would do the same as 2.  You have $r$ flags in a row.  Choose $q$ of them to be white, which gives $n \choose q$ positions for white flags in the row.  Now you have ${n+r-1 \choose r}$ ways to put dividers to put them on the poles, so there are ${n \choose q}{n+r-1 \choose r}$ configurations.  This counts different orders on a pole as different, contradicting our answer to number 1

The approach for 3 will fix number 1.  Put the flags in order on the ground in one of $r!$ ways, then put dividers between them (allowing multiple dividers in each space) to define which flags go on which pole, giving $r!{n+r-1 \choose r}$ configurations where order on the flagpole matters.  For $r=3,n=2$ this gives $3!{4 \choose 3}=24$ possibilities.

Comment: In your last point, do you mean order the flags before raising them?

Comment: Yes.  You just put them in a line on the ground.  Then when you put the $n-1$ dividers in the row the ones before the first divider go on the first pole, the ones between the first and second dividers go on the second and so on.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

(1) and (2) look great. I'm not sure what you mean by "the number of the chosen flags" in (3) -- doesn't the question specify you raise all $r$ flags? I would do (3) by noting that you can choose how to raise the red flags and the white flags independently, and  for each color, you solve by (2).